# TypeScript generic factory function to return type based on instance argument without overloading

Tags: typescript, generics, overloading, typescript-generics

I want to create instance based on instance argument given to factory method. I was able to write following code using overloading. **How to express it using TypeScript generics?**

```js
class Car {
    brand = 'Skoda';
}

class Human {
    name = 'Jan';
}

class Garage {
    lots = 5;
}

class House {
    floors = 2;
}

class NotAllowed {
    anything = 'anything';
}

class Selection {

    pick(what: Car) : Garage;
    pick(what: Human) : House;
    pick(what: any) : any {
        if (what instanceof Car) {
            return new Garage();
        } else if (what instanceof Human) {
            return new House();
        } else {
            throw Error('Not supported')
        }
    }

}

const selection = new Selection();
selection.pick(new Car()).lots; // compiler successfully autocompletes 
selection.pick(new Human()).floors // compiler successfully autocompletes 
selection.pick(new NotAllowed()); // compiler error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `pick()`'s call signature to be a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) method whose parameter is of a generic type [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of your different desired input types, and whose return type is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) which chooses the output type based on the input type:

```
declare class Selection {
  pick<T extends Car | Human>(what: T): T extends Car ? Garage : House;
}
```

This behaves the same for your example calls:

```
const selection = new Selection();
selection.pick(new Car()).lots; // compiler successfully autocompletes 
selection.pick(new Human()).floors // compiler successfully autocompletes 
selection.pick(new NotAllowed()); // compiler error
```

---

Unfortunately your implementation will not be seen as type safe; the type `T` will be *unspecified* inside of the body of `pick()`, and so the compiler does not and cannot verify that `T` is assignable to `Car` even if `what instanceof Car` is true:

```
pick<T extends Car | Human>(what: T): T extends Car ? Garage : House {
  if (what instanceof Car) {
    return new Garage(); // error!
    // Type 'Garage' is not assignable to type 'T extends Car ? Garage : House'
  } else if (what instanceof Human) {
    return new House(); // error!
    // Type 'House' is not assignable to type 'T extends Car ? Garage : House'.
  } else {
    throw Error('Not supported')
  }
}
```

Instead of going on about why this happens, I will just direct you to [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), the relevant open feature request to improve language support for implementing generic functions returning conditional types.

For now you will need to do something like a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```
pick<T extends Car | Human>(what: T): T extends Car ? Garage : House {
  if (what instanceof Car) {
    return new Garage() as T extends Car ? Garage : House;
  } else if (what instanceof Human) {
    return new House() as T extends Car ? Garage : House;
  } else {
    throw Error('Not supported')
  }
}
```

or equivalently, a single call-signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```
pick<T extends Car | Human>(what: T): T extends Car ? Garage : House;
pick(what: Car | Human) {
  if (what instanceof Car) {
    return new Garage();
  } else if (what instanceof Human) {
    return new House();
  } else {
    throw Error('Not supported')
  }
}
```

I know you said you didn't want overloads, but this is usually my solution since adding type assertions everywhere is messier and more tedious.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkvBiFFEgMIgBOehRSARjSMACZIC8SA5AMoBrAPbsQvANwMAvvgYkyFABIBXMG3qMkoSNz4o2kmXKILySAOK0QAc2QEtGYQBcKPAKxSis+aXNLhFSh7BiIAMydhGjckACYvJB9TPwoAORcAQQwnAHcITgdGNgBPZwALAEtgGz1eEvKqmyNvE21waDhEJAARCAVWZwrhYE1Gdj7SGmQzCn4IDD7B4dGtGAr4QQAeABUkCAAPZwgOCmo6AB8kVXVgAD4AChyykGcALiRtgEp33YOjk6otCQAH5LNY7Eh3gEghAEi1jAwAPSIpBlZzOGBQV7ImwVcoqJgAOngwjAiLA6xowigwjCzkR22KMAg-HgNAqMHpFXIKmgiIAzPyAJwARlivkUSDmC3gSxGBFaRDWGwAGjs9odjuxTkDLtc2A8ni8ft8Phr-trAXRQVZWBCoYFgitGBUwkhHs9nEgqlBnGxELSrZ9nVops4VDQRsAIDkwXaIPdPhIkMi9jQqTQAIShLQplGM5l8W22CC8b0UYAuJCKCo2UBMBZIZzCJtM5C8X6agFnEFxkuQq6O0s57x7DBO13uo1en1+4ABt364DBwq5pBhiNRmODmGJ5OpiDpqLZtdEVMF9vQ4Jl7naKs1usgBvIZutwsd81anXWvv2nfXwkR0SMcnVXXNyipWMAFEjxoe5eHSL0oBUGAYCiI52F4T4gNkLQfBzZUtk7C1vyQPU1AND1jQ+U1iK-K1e2LP8rxCNdJyomdgF9f0IEDM4VyAogN0jbRtyYhNgzIM0-nonsbXBZAHRhOFGGkEDkHY6dvS4ucFyuCjlxDRhhK3WMWMTasKDo7sgXk+MBxYlTR3mUDBKbMpIKQGCM3gxCkGQ1D0PyLCcJzfDVnWQQAHl1RkmyLn0m5DU9E0fk-eLGIUhyhxUwioo494e3Im4BLYt0OO07j514t1+KMoSIHDETo1jcS9xw9TvXKrTZx4wMl1K08TNEsyh3atc1Jc1jTwg4RoNg3yqwCtCaAwkKJrCuRWnw+Rhl9fz5kWIYRh4FqpUO2VjvGg6ZTlQlCPuM6zkTT5CScVx9xREkwDWBY6GQ+BEHIMIVGyYpqxUZtvpgBYjgoBhglu477six7tyXF7CQiYQogoVNoYqP7-JUQHoCgEGwYhqHSRhxroCQBGLruh6zsQrJcnyF7PuIGnCcPNMMzkaQgA)

Comment: thanks a lot for comprehensive answer. Actually I have whole list of Cars and Humans, in that case should I use ternary  return type T extends Car ? Garage : Animal ? Wood : ... : never   ?  or is there any better approach ?

Comment: You could write `T extends Car ? Garage : T extends Animal ? Woods : T extends Human ? House : never` but one it's that long you might do better with some more programmatic solution like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9Jo9m).

Comment: Thank a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for.